# Как выровнять текст вертикально по центру кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, input

Почему `vertical-align:middle;` не работает?

```css
.input_button_style {
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 130px;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 37px;
  border: 1px solid #0095ff;
  background-color: #0095ff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.input_font_style {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 19px;
}
.input_input_style {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -410px;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>
      <p class="buttond" style="text-align:center;"><a id="" target="_self" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:19px;  text-decoration: none; padding:10px 20px; color:#ffffff; background-color:#0095ff; border-radius:5px; border: 0px solid #0095ff;">123456</a>
      </p>
    </td>

    <td>
      <p class="buttond" style="text-align:center;"><a id="" download="img.jpg" target="_self" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:19px;  text-decoration: none; padding:10px 20px; color:#ffffff; background-color:#0095ff; border-radius:5px; border: 0px solid #0095ff;">скачать</a>
      </p>
    </td>

    <td>

      <div class="input_button_style">
        <div class="input_font_style">выбрать файл</div>
        <input type="file" name="img" id="uploadimage" size="1" class="input_input_style">
      </div>


    </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как выровнять текст вертикально по центру кнопки?

Используйте свойство [line-height](http://htmlbook.ru/css/line-height) для `.input_button_style`

```css
.input_button_style {
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 130px;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 37px;
  border: 1px solid #0095ff;
  background-color: #0095ff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.input_font_style {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 19px;
}
.input_input_style {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -410px;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input_button_style">
  <div class="input_font_style">Выбрать файл</div>
  <input type="file" name="img" id="uploadimage" size="1" class="input_input_style">
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо) а как мошно убрать большие отступы, сверху и слева?
она мне таблицу растягивает

Comment: если Вы имеете ввиду отступ слева от кнопки, уберите `margin-left: 10px;`, если Вы имеете ввиду другое, то уточните пожалуйста какие отступы Вы имеете ввиду. Кроме этого у Вас могут быть большие отступы из-за значений `margin-top` и `margin-left` в `.input_input_style`

Comment: да, я имею ввиду - сверху снизу,   margin-top:-50px; margin-left:-410px;  я убрать не могу, т.к. от них завизит положение активной области

Comment: @кузьмич не видя Вашей таблицы трудно сказать, однако могу предположить, что Вам вместо отрицательного `margin` нужно задать `position:absolute`, `width:100%` и задать необходимый `heigth`.

Comment: я отредактировал вопрос и вставил ее

Comment: @кузьмич Пожалуйста помните, если У Вас возник новый вопрос, необходимо задать его как новый, **отдельный** вопрос. Что касается Вашей таблицы, то я сейчас не вижу, что кнопки растягивают ячейки - http://prntscr.com/dbzkne Перепроверьте пожалуйста.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49139/discussion-between-alex-and-).